# Heroku's mailgun account says temporarily disabled

Tags: heroku, phpmailer, mailgun

Heroku's mailgun account says temporarily disabled. " Business verification is required". How do you do the verification so as start sending mails through heroku app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this information [here](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/202850080-What-does-business-verification-is-required-mean-)

(first result for Google search "business verification mailgun")

Comment: nice! can you please accept my answer then??? :D
the symbol under the number to the left <